# Не могу настроить управление игры, написанную на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

файл Alien_invasion.py

```
import sys                      # Модуль sys  будет завершать по команде игру
import pygame                   # Модуль pygame содержит всю функциаеалность для     создания игры
from settings import Settings   # иморптруем settings
from ship1 import Ship          # импортируем ship
import game_functions as gf
def run_game():                 #   Определяем функцию
   pygame.init()               #   Инициализруем настроки pygame
   ai_settings = Settings()      # Ипортируем класс settigs и вставляем ai_settings
   screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width,                             ai_settings.screen_height)) # Используем атрибуты для создания формата окна 

   screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1700, 1000))    #    Создаем отображаемую область, аргуметы означают размеры игрового окна
   pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")       #    Отображение названия игры     
   bg_color = (230, 230, 230)                          # выбрали цвет экрана
   ship = Ship(screen)                             # Создаем корабль до начала цикла while

   while True:                                     # Запускаем цикл
        gf.check_events(ship)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship)                                     
        for event in pygame.event.get():            # Чтобы наша прогрмма реагировала на акие либо действия напишем цикл for. Используем метод pygame.event.get():, чтобы получать доступ к событиям
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:           # Пишем if для обнаружение и обработки конкретных действий
                sys.exit()                          # Например мы закрываем программа, он обнаруживает  pygame.QUIT: и вызывает sys.exit() который завершает игру
            screen.fill(bg_color)                   # Заполняем экран выбранным цветом фона
            screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)       # Используем атрибут для создания цвкта фона
            ship.blitme()                           # Выводим корабль поверх фона
        

        pygame.display.flip()                       #   При запуске буде твыводиться новый экран
    
run_game()  #   Запускаем игру
```

файл ship.py

```
import pygame

class Ship():
    def __init__(self, screen):
       self.screen = screen
       self.image = pygame.image.load('/Users/alexey/Dropbox/Мой Mac (FeelQueen’s iMac)/Documents/Python/rocket-147466_640.bmp') # Возврашает картинку коробля
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()       # С поиощью метода get получили изображение
       self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()    #
       self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx    
       self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom      # центрируем изоюражение
       self.moving_right = False
       self.moving_left = False
    def update(self):                                   # Этот метод перемешает корабль, есди флаг self.moving_right = True
       if self.moving_right == True:
          self.rect.centerx += 1
           if self.moving_left == True:
            self.rect.centerx -= 1
    def blitme(self):
           self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

setting.py

```
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1700
        self.screen_height = 1000
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        self.ship_speed_factor = 8
```

game_funcyions.py

```
import sys
import pygame

def check_events(ship):                             # Реакции на нажатие клавиш
   for event in pygame.event.get():  
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:         
             sys.exit() 
         elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:      
             if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                 ship.moving_right = True
             if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                     ship.moving_left = True
             elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                 if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    ship.moving_right = False 
                 if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                     ship.moving_left = False
def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship):          # Обновление экрана при нажатии клавиш, то есть отображение перемешения корабля 
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Когда я запускаю программу, нажимаю кнопку вправо и цикл выполняешься без остановки, должно быть так: Я отпускаю правую кнопку и перемещение корабля останавливается, так же не понимаю почему кнопка влево не работает от слова совсем

Answer (score 2):

Разберитесь с табуляциями. Как сейчас у вас код не скомпилируется. Но если убрать один пробел, то проблемы с табуляцией и логикой останутся:

```
   if self.moving_right == True:
      self.rect.centerx += 1
      if self.moving_left == True:
        self.rect.centerx -= 1
```

Тут `if self.moving_left` проверяется только если выполняется `if self.moving_right`. Проверки должны быть на одном уровне:

```
   if self.moving_right == True:
      self.rect.centerx += 1
   if self.moving_left == True:
      self.rect.centerx -= 1
```

Тоже самое с проверками на нажатие и отпускание клавиш:

```
 elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:      
     ...
     elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
```

Они должны быть на одном уровне:

```
 elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:      
 ...
 elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
```

Comment: Помогло спасибо, но теперь проблема в том что я нажал кнопку вправо> корабль пошел в право, но при этом когда отпустил кнопку, он продолжил движение в право. Так быть не должно

Comment: @АлексейКарнеенко Оба указанных мной фрагмента кода исправили?

Comment: Да)))))], но осталось как и написал выше

Comment: @АлексейКарнеенко Странно. Ну, дальше не знаю. Проверьте остальные отступы и логику. Попробуйте `print`-ов накидать везде и посмотрите, что где как.

Comment: А причем тут принты, и все остальное порядке